# C# Hashtable template match

Tags: c#, templates, hashtable, subset

Which is the best way to determine whether a Hashtable contains all keys/values of another Hashtable ?

This can also be interpreted as: how to determine whether a Hashtable is a *subset* of another Hashtable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over all the key/value pairs in the "smaller" hashtable and check whether they exist (with the right values) in the "bigger" hashtable, basically. You could do a `Count` check to start with to check that the "smaller" table really is smaller (or the same size) to start with, of course.

This will be O(n) where n is the size of the smaller hashtable, assuming reasonable hashes in the larger one and constant time equality checking. You can't do better than that.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like there is no such built-in functionality so I'll have to write it myself